# How to order Firebase Database so its NOT in alphabetic order

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database for an Android application for a restaurant project I am working on. In the database, it holds all of the order information, except it orders it in alphabetic order. Is there a way to structure the database so that it is not in alphabetic order. I would like it to have certain attributes first, such as order number, date and time. Then have it list the items in the order so that when I display the information, the order number and such doesn't show up randomly in different places for each order. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can order the results based on one of your child like this :

```
// My top posts by number of stars
String myUserId = getUid();
Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts")
                                         .child(myUserId)
                                         .orderByChild("starCount");
myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});
```

Here the results are ordered by a child "starCount"

More explanation is in here : [FIrebase sort and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)